# MYSQL filter our same rows that are next to each other

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

I have this table, similar to the one below.
Table show player points:

- **s** main player points
- **d** sub main points;
- **date** when it is calculated.

I want to be able to filter rows that are same as **s** and **d** staying next to each other. Date should be as the last last one that are the same.

For example, here we should skip ri - 13 as it is the same as ri -12. Also skip ri - 15,19,20,21,22,23 and so on. But rows 28, 29,30,31 should not be skipped and grouped.

I'm asking because GROUP BY for my case do not work. Any ideas?

Table example:

```
ri  date        s   d
1   2016-05-23  4   355
2   2016-05-16  4   352
3   2016-05-09  4   349
4   2016-05-02  4   352
5   2016-04-25  4   358
6   2016-04-18  4   359
7   2016-04-11  4   200
8   2016-04-04  4   201
9   2016-03-21  4   198
10  2016-03-07  4   199
11  2016-02-29  4   201
12  2016-02-22  4   203
13  2016-02-15  4   203
14  2016-02-08  4   200
15  2016-02-01  4   200
16  2016-01-18  4   201
17  2016-01-11  4   198
18  2016-01-04  4   183
19  2015-12-28  4   183
20  2015-12-21  4   183
21  2015-12-14  4   183
22  2015-12-07  4   183
23  2015-11-30  4   183
24  2015-11-23  4   182
25  2015-11-16  4   149
26  2015-11-09  4   148
27  2015-11-02  4   145
28  2015-10-26  4   109
29  2015-10-19  4   110
30  2015-10-12  4   109
31  2015-10-05  4   110
32  2015-09-28  4   106
33  2015-09-21  4   108
34  2015-09-14  4   109
35  2015-08-31  5   108
36  2015-08-24  5   108
37  2015-08-17  5   136
38  2015-08-10  5   136
39  2015-08-03  4   123
40  2015-07-27  4   122
41  2015-07-20  4   125
42  2015-07-13  4   126
43  2015-06-29  4   130
44  2015-06-22  4   128
45  2015-06-15  4   126
46  2015-06-08  4   120
47  2015-05-25  9   120
48  2015-05-18  9   122
49  2015-05-11  9   121
50  2015-05-04  9   119
51  2015-04-27  9   122
52  2015-04-20  10  124
53  2015-04-13  9   173
54  2015-04-06  9   172
55  2015-03-23  8   174
56  2015-03-09  7   89
57  2015-03-02  7   89
58  2015-02-23  7   92
59  2015-02-16  7   96
60  2015-02-09  8   93
61  2015-02-02  9   88
62  2015-01-19  4   89
63  2015-01-12  4   89
64  2015-01-05  4   94
```

Comment: Hi to clarify

currently I do

    `SELECT date, s, d FROM player_points WHERE player_id = 1497103 AND date > '2015-01-01'`

If I do

    `SELECT date, s, d FROM player_points WHERE player_id = 1497103 AND date > '2015-01-01' GROUP BY s,d`

It will skip for me some results that are important.

Comment: imo, Please never post code in comments - **it is unreadable**. Instead _add it to your question_.  That way, 1) We can easily understand it. 2) New people  don't have to read the comments to find out all the information that you decided to explain to us. After that you can delete the comment as it just makes the thread harder to understand. If you get a working answer then you don't need to bother :)

Comment: I know exactly what the data set looks like. But I have no idea what the desired result set should look like. I wonder if you can fix that in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Coulb be you need a join   ..

```
select a.*, b.* 
from my_table as a 
inner join my_table as b on a.ri  != b.ri 
where (a.d - b.d) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `not exists`. This would select the first of many rows which have the same s and d.

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2 
                  where t1.ri = t2.ri+1 and t1.s = t2.s and t1.d = t2.d)
```